# Adding a border to a P tag element under certain conditions in Sass

Tags: css, sass

Is there a way in Sass to declare if height exceeds 40%, add a border of 1px ?

```
p {
    font-family: $regular-font;
    color: $color-neutral-50;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid $color-border;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to achieve this. You would have to have an additional class that set the min-height to 40% then did something.

If you know that at a certain screen height (or width if text is wrapping), the P element will be larger than 40% of the assigned screen space, you could use a media query to get the size of the screen, and conditionally set styling on the P tag.

```
@media (max-height: 850px){
   p {
      /* do something here */
   }
}
```

There is another way of doing this via javascript of course, get the height of both elements and work out if the P tag is larger than 40%, then set styling or a class based on that.

Comment: You say "No, there is no way to achieve this.", but this is achieveable with javascript and Element queries.

Comment: @L.Copley yes, but the question specifically says this "Is there a way in Sass". I am aware of it being possible in JavaScript, but the question specifically targeted SASS, so my answer did too.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are **Element queries**. These are media queries that are influenced by elements properties instead of the viewport. This isn't a feature of CSS yet, but there are libraries and preprocessors which can achieve this.

https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Hopefully this will be added at some point. The specification is still under development:
[Element Queries specification](https://tomhodgins.github.io/element-queries-spec/element-queries.html)

Otherwise, you can achieve this with javascript.